# How to add launchers near username in whisker menu (upper right corner)?

Tags: xubuntu, launcher, xfce, appmenu, whisker

Subj. Currently, there are two items: "all settings", "lock" and "log out". I want to add another one, power off. I created a new item through "edit applications", copied everything from logout launcher, but it didn't appear there. Seems like only predefined launchers can be there...

[image: Screenshot]